# How can I use OAuth and PHP without using the oauth-php library?

Tags: php, mysql, api, authentication, oauth

I need to build a script that uses OAuth authentication to connect to Foursquare's API, but oauth-php library is too complicated.

Any one page scripts that don't use MySQL? I would rather just use cookies.

Comment: Great question. oauth-php is indeed way too complex. Good example of a library gone astray.

Comment: +1 for a great question. I was just about to post something similar! :)

Comment: anyone find any simple ones for oauth2?

Answer (score 5):

This library is really simple to use:

http://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple/

Comment: This one is also better maintained and has a painfully simple example included in the source as of this August. I'd opt for this one (as I did!).

Comment: Is this OAuth 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: This is OAuth 1.0 , see that it's got signature methods.. OAuth 2.0 doesn't deal with such things in general.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the oauth portion of the library at http://code.google.com/p/photobucket-api-php5/

Also, the `Zend_Oauth` module (available in the incubator, and hopefully in the next Framework release) is excellent and easy to use.  It just looks like a `Zend_Http_Client` after you set it up.

Comment: I hardly think anything Zend qualifies as "simpler".

Answer (score 0):

I have used this library: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/ 
and now able to understand why there is two different thing consumer and server well basically Its seems example here is doing the same thing here.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use oauth-php library you can even write your own small lib doing this.
You can for example check my the simplest and the smallest implementation of the OAuth with Twitter and Linked:

https://github.com/adrianmalik/php-oauth/blob/master/README.md

There will find everything you need to do this.

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried this one?

https://svn.iamcal.com/public/php/lib_oauth/lib_oauth.php

It wouldn't fit in one page but it's really simple.